# cross domain request with ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain, activexobject

I want to send request by using only **ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")** from IE8, to **Cross-Domain** which allows cross domain request.

```
var url = "127.0.0.1:9845";
xObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
if(xObj!=null)
{
    xObj.open("GET", url,false); 
    xObj.send(null);
}
```

but, it display **"Permission denied"** on `xObj.open("GET", url,false);` .

anybody help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't. Use [XDomainRequest](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx) instead. (Or tell people to get a modern browser).

Comment: it is compulsory to use ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") in my case...

Comment: You would need to post to a server side script on the same domain that issued the request to the other domain and then returned the response by proxy.

Comment: @PiyushSonani — That's a bizarre requirement. Challenge it.